# RTL support for wysiwyg editor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

How can I include RTL(right to left) support for my wysiwyg editor.
I already tried `document.execCommand('dirRTL', false, null)`. But it is not working.
But how is Gmail able to do it. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: its solution depends on the type of plugin.

Comment: what do you mean by plugin...I need an pure javascript solution :(

Comment: i mean type of your wysiwyg editor. its better to provide more details.

Comment: Actually i myself am developing the wysiwyg editor. Need to add a new feature to the editor

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question, anyway I have just implemented a solution for that so I share it.

I use the [bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails), which is based on [bootstrap3-wysiwyg](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg) code.

The editor is created with an iframe, so what I do is simply:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $('iframe.wysihtml5-sandbox').each(function(i) {
    $(this).contents().find("body").css({'direction':'rtl', 'font-family':'Arial'});
  });
})
</script>
```

(I use `each` function since I have several editors)

Answer (score 1):

No command is available for text direction in execCommand.

Below is my solution using "insertHTML" to Insert an HTML string at the insertion point.

```js
//Consider tag as the name of the command to execute eg. bold,underline,justifyRight,...

if(tag=='rtl' || tag=='ltr' ){
    var s=document.getSelection();   
    if(s==''){
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<p dir='"+tag+"'></p>");
    }else{
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span dir='"+tag+"'>"+ document.getSelection()+"</span>");
    }
}else{
    //Default
    document.execCommand(tag,false,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news is that the operating systems take care of the real problems when it comes to RTL (Right To Left) document orientations. 
You just have to target your elements you want to apply RTL to and add text-align to RIGHT and direction to RTL. You'll see the real result only if you start typing in arabian, as not only the writing will start from right to left, but its orientation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution:
edit file: wysihtml5-0.3.0.js and find line wysihtml5.dom.setAttributes and add folowing line: 
"direction":          "rtl",